# Display problem with intel card on dell

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a dual-boot system with win10 and ubuntu 16.0.4
It runs on DEL Inspiron 15 series 5000 (5558).
It has dual graphics, intel and nividia geforce 920 M
during the last ubuntu update I lost my luancher , toolbar and dach. my monitor was not detected and it is recognized as built in display.

I tried many things to fix that but nothing worked. 
However, the last command I tried is:

```
sudo apt-get purge intel-\*
```

Due to that the intel driver is gone. Now I can get even the login screen it is only the background. I only can log in with shell.

How do I get back to the normal graphical login screen and 
after that How to solve the original problem.